# Is there a free, available document with most iso 639 (languages) codes?

Tags: iso

iso.org sells them, but it's $140 USD for just the ISO 639-1 codes. That's just absurd.
Also, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazilian_Portuguese) says that the ISO 639-1 code for brazilian portugues is 'pt-BR', yet ISO 693-1 standard use just 2 letters. Can anyone explain the reason behind that?

Answer (score 6):

You can get a full list of ISO639-1 codes as a SKOS concept (rdf) in various formats from the Library of Congress website: http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/iso639-1.html
ISO639-2 is a more complete list of 3 letter country codes (over 500 vs 180 for iso639-1) is also available on the website.

The "pt-BR" code for Brazilian Portuguese you mention is not actually the ISO639-1 code, but a composite code made up of the ISO639-1 code for portuguese "pt" and the ISO3166-1 country code for Brazil "BR". These are combined following best practice defined in RFC5646: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646 .

The good news is, as you see in RFC5646, there is a standard for saying "Portuguese as spoken in Brazil": "pt-BR", so anyone wanting to tag something as Brazilian Portuguese would construct the tag this way. The bad news is that, as of yet, i cannot find an authoritative list of these defined as resources :(
Hope this helps!

Comment: I wouldn't bother with ISO 639-2; it has basically been superseded by ISO 639-3. Also check [IETF BCP 47](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47), which combines RFC 5646 and RFC 4647.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [csv](https://github.com/serghei-topor/language-list-csv) file with list of ISO 639-1, ISO 639-2b, ISO-639-2t, ISO-639-3 languages. It contains I think list of all existing languages in the world. I retrieved it from [language_list](https://github.com/scsmith/language_list) gem

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the **[`datasets/language-codes`](https://github.com/datasets/language-codes)** github repo.

Answer (score 0):

I found a smallish list with the most common languages and it's ISO 639-1 codes in [Oracle's website](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13214_01/wli/docs92/xref/xqisocodes.html#wp1252447).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes) has a more complete list, with 555 entries with ISO 639-1,2,3 and 5, scope and type.